# How to read instance variables set by accessors inside the same class?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, accessor

I have a curiosity regarding which is the preferred way of accessing instance variables **inside** a class that has defined an accessor for that instance variable.

One way would be by referencing the instance variable directly:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :attribute

  def meth
    puts @attribute
  end
end
```

The other way would be by calling the reader created by the accessor:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :attribute

  def meth
    puts attribute
  end
end
```

It's a small difference, but I am curious which is the preferred approach and why. The only advantage I see on readers vs. direct instance variable access is that it is easier to stub a reader inside a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to go through the accessors.  For instance, if you access the instance variable directly, and then you later convert the value with the reader, then accessing the instance variable directly won't see that change.

Using the accessors rather than accessing the instance variables directly causes `one small quirk` when you want to use the accessor to set the value of the instance variable.

Normally when you write:

```
some_meth 10
```

...ruby will interpret that as:

```
self.some_meth(10)
```

But if you write:

```
age = 10
```

...ruby will not interpret that as:

```
self.age=(10)
```

Instead, ruby will create a local variable named `age` and set it to 10, which has no affect on an instance variable named `@age`.

In order to call the setter for @age, you have to explicitly write `self`:

```
self.age = 10
```

Here is a complete example:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :age

  def age=(val)
    @age = val * 7
  end

  def initialize val 
    self.age = val  #age = val  will not call the setter
  end

end

d = Dog.new 10
puts d.age  #=> 70
```

Comment: Indeed, you've also added 2 "votes" for the accessor, although the difference is not that significant. But the accessor just adds that "usability" value to your code.